# Python dictionary search based on value pattern

Tags: python

I have dictionary myDict with following and values

```
   myDict:
     {u'E1': (u'disabled', u'10G-CR'),
      u'E10': (u'notconnect', u'NP'),
      u'E11': (u'notconnect', u'NP'),
      u'E12': (u'connected', u'10G-CR')
```

I would like to define search filter in value as 'notconnect'.

So output will be

```
 u'E10': (u'notconnect', u'NP') 
 u'E11': (u'notconnect', u'NP')
```

Thanks

Comment: What stops you from doing this? Invalid syntax, I presume?

Comment: Topic : Python dictionary search filter in value.

Comment: your comment looks pretty cryptic, could you elaborate please?

Comment: @ForceBru - indeed - syntax

Comment: Have a look at [toolz.valfilter](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.dicttoolz.valfilter).

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach. Create a list of keys, that contain `notconnect`. You can use it to do which ever look ups you would need later.

```
>>> filter(lambda key: d[key][0] == 'notconnect', d.keys())
[u'E11', u'E10']
```

*Alternatively*, returned a filtered sub-dictionary using a dictionary comprehension.

```
>>> print {key : value for key, value in d.items() if value[0] == 'notconnect'}
{u'E11': (u'notconnect', u'NP'), u'E10': (u'notconnect', u'NP')}
```

Comment: Works! Thanks @mrdomoboto

Comment: If you like my answer, please feel free to give it an upvote @user2178754

Answer (score 0):

First of all the syntax for dictionary is not correct. Refer [Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

```
In [39]: myDict = {u'E1': (u'disabled', u'10G-CR'),
  u'E10': (u'notconnect', u'NP'),
  u'E11': (u'notconnect', u'NP'),
  u'E12': (u'connected', u'10G-CR')}

In [40]: expectedResult = [{d:myDict[d]} for d in myDict if myDict[d][0] == "notconnect"]

In [41]: expectedResult
Out[41]: [{u'E11': (u'notconnect', u'NP')}, {u'E10': (u'notconnect', u'NP')}]
```